# Pervasive ODBC connection from Linux Ubuntu 64bit - DSNADD not found

Tags: linux, odbc, database-connection, pervasive

I'm trying to connect to Pervasive via ODBC from an Ubuntu 64bit server.

I did the following things:

1. Installed **unixodbc** with apt-get command.
2. Downloaded the **Pervasive SQL 64bit Client 11.20** from the [Pervasive site](http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/Pages/PSQL-v11-Linux-Downloads.aspx) (don't know if this is the correct one I have to install)
3. Extracted the archive and moved to */usr/local/psql*

Now, in */usr/local/psql/bin* I can only see:

- clilcadm64
- isql64
- psregedit64
- psregsvr64

No trace of **dsnadd** to set the connection driver and the DSN... What I did wrong?

(I'm a Linux novice so any kind of suggestion would be really appreciated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the 64 bit driver if you are using a 64 bit application.  If you have a 32 bit application, you need the 32 bit driver.

The `dsnadd` utility seems to be 32 bit.  You would need to install the 32 bit client to get that tool.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get a pervasive client set up on ubuntu as well.

This article was helpful to me, and includes a version of dsnadd edited for 64 bit.

https://tron2001.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/psql-64-bit-linux-client-installation/

Read the script to be sure, but I don't think you even need this dsnadd utility, as you can edit the odbc.ini manually to do the same thing.